# Terribly slow query inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my application I have products and categories. A product can be in multiple categories. So I have two tables: CwObject (products) and EntityObjectLink (Link between product and category). I have one query that is used a lot but even after days of tweeking it is terribly slow. There are aproximately 400K records in CwObject and 1.2M in EntityObjectLink.

This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP (99999) 
    CwObject.* 
FROM 
    CwObject 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.EntityObjectLink ON CwObject.CwObject_Guid = EntityObjectLink.EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwObject_Guid 
WHERE
    EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwEntity_Guid = '9a0e41d7-a472-445e-b94f-44fe1a1506b3' 
    AND CwObject_CwSiteCluster_Guid = '0f178176-9720-41c7-9528-99fdf30005e8' 
    AND CwObject_EntityType = 1 
    AND (CwObject_Predecessor_Guid IS NULL)
ORDER BY 
    CwObject_Name ASC
```

`EntityObjectLink` has a relevant clustered index:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwEntity_Guid] ASC,
                       [EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwObject_Guid] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

The `CwObject` table has a relevant index:

```
NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ClusterEntitytypePredecessorStatusClusteraccount] 
ON [dbo].[CwObject]([CwObject_CwSiteCluster_Guid] ASC,
                    [CwObject_EntityType] ASC,
                    [CwObject_Predecessor_Guid] ASC,
                    [CwObject_Status] ASC,
                    [CwObject_ClusterAccount_Guid] ASC)
INCLUDE (% ALL other columns%) 
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

If I use the query optimiser it tells me the query uses both indexes. But I see a couple of things I don't understand:

1. It warns me that there are no column statistics for entity type and predecessorguid. Could it be because I just added the index?
2. There is a huge difference between the actual and estimated row read on the `CwObjects` table.

If I look at the live query statistics the query reads 171K records in `CwObjects` with an index seek (why a seek?). Then does a merge join on the `EntityObjectLink` table where it reads 2.5K records. It would have been much more effective to do it the other way around.

I am really, really stuck here... Can anyone help?

Here is the execution plan: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlCbN2sexrJ-hNJjeSR9cZPOEpOHww

UPDATE:

AtoStats are ON, a few hours old.

Almost all time is consumed in the index seek on CwObject...

UPDATE 2:

I forced the statistics to update on the `cwObjects` table. This made a huge difference! The query is almost 10 times faster!

Comment: It may improve a bit (or a lot) to have a compound index  on (`EntityObjectLink_LinkedCwEntity_Guid, CwObject_CwSiteCluster_Guid`) and another one to `CwObject_Name` Try that.

Comment: please post execution plan

Comment: Have you tried adding CwObject_Guid to the clustered index of CwObject after the first key column?

Comment: How do I post the executionplan? Stackoverflow is complaining it is to much text...?

Comment: post link to skydrive or drop box

Comment: Executionplan: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlCbN2sexrJ-hNJjeSR9cZPOEpOHww

Comment: Your stats are way out ..estimated (1779),actual around 2 lakhs

Comment: Jorge, I added the compound index. Did not change anything.  The name index was already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have statistics on some of the columns, hence you get this warning in your execution plan:

> Columns With No Statistics:
>   [compareware].[dbo].[CwObject].CwObject_EntityType;
>   [compareware].[dbo].[CwObject].CwObject_Predecessor_Guid

This results in an Actual Number of rows of 174480 while the estimated number of rows was 1779,2.

Try activating the `auto create statistics` on the database, or create statistics on those columns manually.

Comment: The auto create statistics was on. But I forced to create them manually. Made a HUGE difference (10 times faster).